# Am trying to import Seriously.js into a meteor application, am receiving an object typeerror

Tags: javascript, node.js, oop, meteor, html5-video

I am trying to use the Seriously.js library (https://github.com/brianchirls/Seriously.js/) in a Meteor application.  I have placed the library in an /imports folder in my meteor application, and I am exporting a variable Seriously from seriously.js at the very top over the entire function:

```
export var Seriously = (function (root, factory) {
'use strict';
if (typeof define === 'function' && define.amd) {
    // AMD. Register as an anonymous module.
    define('seriously', function () {
        var Seriously = factory(root);
        if (!root.Seriously) {
            root.Seriously = Seriously;
        }
        return Seriously;
    });
} else if (typeof exports === 'object') {
    // Node. Does not work with strict CommonJS, but
    // only CommonJS-like enviroments that support module.exports,
    // like Node.
    module.exports = factory(root);
.
.
.
etc.
```

The rest of the Seriously.js code is the same.  Then, in a client script, I am importing as such:

```
import {Seriously} from '/imports/seriously/seriously.js';
```

I then have client code.  However, when running the code, the browser throws this error:

```
meteor.js?hash=ae8b8af…:930 Exception from Tracker afterFlush function:
2016-06-09 21:30:19.486 meteor.js?hash=ae8b8af…:930 TypeError: _seriously.Seriously is not a constructor
```

which references this part of my code:

```
var seriously = new Seriously();
```

and compiled in meteor:

```
var seriously = new _seriously.Seriously();
```

I have tried various ways to export the Seriously class into meteor yet nothing seems to be working and I run into the same error.  Is there any way to properly import this library into meteor?

Comment: For the record this happens with a brand new meteor application as well.  I have a feeling I am not constructing the object properly but I have no idea how to export the library properly in the first place.  Placing Seriously.js into a /client/lib folder and referencing that from my client script results in it not being found.  When I had that issue with a different library, moving that to the /imports folder, exporting that as a variable, then importing that into the client in a similar way worked.

Answer (score 2):

Since you're having trouble with a brand new meteor application as well, we'll start from a new app:

```
meteor create myapp
cd myapp
meteor npm install
meteor
```

Nothing fancy here, we're just creating a basic application. We want to use the module system provided by Meteor which will ensure that our code only runs when we ask it to. To do that, we'll place our library in the `imports` folder and Meteor will only bundle and include that file if it's referenced from another file using an `import` statement. We can put our `seriously.js` in the following folder:

```
imports/seriously/seriously.js
```

If we stick to our default new app, we can edit the `client/main.js` file to import it and that's where things will differ.

We need to use an import statement without curly braces like:

```
import Seriously from '/imports/seriously/seriously.js';
```

The part inside curly braces in an `import` statement are *named exports*. To support that, the library must do something like `export { Something, SomethingElse, etc. }`.

Seriously is standard 3rd party JS library and does not use this syntax so we fall back to `export default Something`. When importing without curly braces, we're simply assigning that default export to the variable identifier we've chose, for example, `Seriously`.

With the `import` working, we can now use Seriously when the template is rendered:

```
Template.hello.onRendered(function helloOnRendered() {
  var seriously = new Seriously();

  var icon = seriously.source('#icon');
  var target = seriously.target('#canvas');
  target.source = icon;

  seriously.go();
});
```

Regarding the effects, if you need them which will obviously be the case, we're going to encounter more problems due to the new parsing/import code used by Meteor in 1.3.

If you try to import an effect like this:

```
import Seriously from '/imports/seriously/seriously.js';
import '/imports/seriously/effects/seriously.vignette.js';
```

The output from Meteor will be:

```
Unable to resolve some modules:

  "seriously" in /Users/HiDeo/test/myapp/imports/seriously/effects/seriously.vignette.js (web.browser)

If you notice problems related to these missing modules, consider running:

  meteor npm install --save seriously
```

Loading this in a web browser will result in `Uncaught Error: Cannot find module 'seriously'`.

This problem is described in [this post](https://forums.meteor.com/t/why-your-jquery-plugins-may-be-failing-in-1-3-1/20739) on their forum but not addressed at the moment.

If we look at [the source code](https://github.com/brianchirls/Seriously.js/blob/master/effects/seriously.vignette.js#L5-L16) for this vignette effect, we can see that the loading mechanism is identical to the one described in the forum post and having problems.

In our case, `factory(require('seriously'));` will be executed but there is no module 'seriously'. At stated in the post and until the issue is addressed, we'll need to modify this loading mechanism to execute `factory(require('/imports/seriously/seriously.js'));` instead. The whole block would look like this:

```
if (typeof define === 'function' && define.amd) {
  // AMD. Register as an anonymous module.
  define(['seriously'], factory);
} else if (typeof exports === 'object') {
  // Node/CommonJS
  factory(require('/imports/seriously/seriously.js'));
} else {
  if (!root.Seriously) {
    root.Seriously = { plugin: function (name, opt) { this[name] = opt; } };
  }
  factory(root.Seriously);
}
```

We can then modify our code to use this new effect:

```
Template.hello.onRendered(function helloOnRendered() {
  var seriously = new Seriously();

  var icon = seriously.source('#icon');
  var target = seriously.target('#canvas');

  var vignette = seriously.effect('vignette');
  vignette.source = icon;
  vignette.amount = 10;

  target.source = vignette;

  seriously.go();
});
```

And after a reload, the effect will be applied:

[image: Effect]

Unfortunately, we'll need to do this for all the effects used in the application until the issue is addressed or fixed.

Comment: Does this work for you? When I do this with the entire seriously library in the `/imports/seriously/` folder the meteor build process hangs at `Processing files with ecmascript`

Comment: Yeah I tested it while writing the answer with the latest Meteor version. The processing can take a little while but after that you should be done.

Comment: OK, good to know that it eventually did build. Mine's been running for 8 min on a brand new i7 machine. How long did yours take to build? Thanks!

Comment: Just tried to edit `seriously.js` to force a full rebuild, it took ~30s to build and refresh the browser. And it give you no error, it just hangs? Can you try `meteor --verbose`? You should also try to rename the seriously `.js` files to `.es5.js`.

Comment: Ahh the `seriously.js` file alone loads just fine. However, as I understand it, that file relies upon all the other files in the library. So if I only have that file in the imports folder Meteor works fine, yet I won't be able to use seriously.js to do any of the manipulations like vignette (per the tutorial - https://github.com/brianchirls/Seriously.js/wiki/Tutorial). To do that I need to add the entire library of files. When I do that the Meteor hangs. Let me know if I'm missing something there.

Comment: I edited my post to provide a full example on how to load effects in Meteor 1.3 with the following steps: fixing an issue, loading the effect, applying the effect and getting the expected result.

Comment: Thanks that all worked perfectly. I really appreciate the detailed answer.

Answer (score 0):

If anyone is here looking for the same problem but related to npm/yarn installations the answer from HiDeo also applies but you need to replace the define(...) above that.

```
if (typeof define === 'function' && define.amd) {
  // AMD. Register as an anonymous module.
  //define(['seriously'], factory);
  factory(require('/imports/seriously/seriously.js'));
} else if (typeof exports === 'object') {
  // Node/CommonJS
  factory(require('/imports/seriously/seriously.js'));
} else {
  if (!root.Seriously) {
    root.Seriously = { plugin: function (name, opt) { this[name] = opt; } };
  }
  factory(root.Seriously);
}
```